# Check if Android app is running on a Google test device?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-test-lab, prelaunch, internal-app-sharing

I recently uploaded an app bundle to [Internal App Sharing](https://play.google.com/console/about/internalappsharing/), and was surprised to see that on my backend, there were 7 new users of this new app version just a few seconds later. I was especially surprised because I am the only person with access to the app on Internal App Sharing, and I hadn't even installed the update yet.

So I guess Google is running something similar to pre-launch testing when uploading to Internal App Sharing. This is annoying, because it fills up my servers user table with irrelevant noise.

Can I detect these devices reliably somehow? I tried detecting the presence of `firebase.test.lab` in `Settings.System`, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45070039/930640), but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As a developer och you can disable tests-reports in Google Play Console. Pre-launch tests, config (or something, I get the UI in Swedish so I currently don't see the English names of them.)

NOTE: I have not tested myself (as I want the testing) and I think they will still do some tests when you want to launch things.